# GraalVM called by gluonfx:compile get stucked at "Garbage collector: Serial GC"

Tags: javafx, graalvm, gluon, graalvm-native-image, gluonfx

**Problem:**
I did `mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:compile` in a project and it follow the steps properly, but when GraalVM is called and it gets to "Garbage collector: Serial GC", it simply get stucked and don't move to the next step.

**Environment info:**

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 desktop amd64 running in VMware 16 with classic instalation, with 2,25 GB of RAM.
- Dependecies: Installed OpenJDK 19 with apt. Installed "GraalVM SVM java17 Linux Gluon 22.1.0.1" and "Apache Maven-3.8.6", which are in /opt/graalvm and /opt/maven.
- Project: I used the archetype from NetBeans: "Gluon - Single View Project" and changed nothing from it and its pom.xml

**Log:**

> [Sat Dec 09 12:49:54 BRT 2023][INFO] We will now compile your code for
> aarch64-linux-android. This may take some time. [Sat Dec 09 12:49:57
> BRT 2023][INFO] [SUB] Warning: Ignoring server-mode native-image
> argument --no-server. [Sat Dec 09 12:50:07 BRT 2023][INFO] [SUB]
> ======================================================================================================================== [Sat Dec 09 12:50:07 BRT 2023][INFO] [SUB] GraalVM Native Image:
> Generating 'com.gluonpadrao.gluonpadrao' (shared library)... [Sat Dec
> 09 12:50:07 BRT 2023][INFO] [SUB]
> ======================================================================================================================== [Sat Dec 09 12:50:14 BRT 2023][INFO] [SUB] [1/7] Initializing...
> (14.2s @ 0.15GB) [Sat Dec 09 12:50:14 BRT 2023][INFO] [SUB]  Version
> info: 'GraalVM 22.1.0.1 Java 17 CE' [Sat Dec 09 12:50:14 BRT
> 2023][INFO] [SUB]  Garbage collector: Serial GC

I tried to change Java Heap Size with `MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1" mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:build` and it didn't work and it doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: I can't say the GC issue is directly related to VMWare, but have you tried a different alternatives to VMWare? As documented [here](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_android), you can use WSL2 or GitHub actions, see https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_android_github_actions.

Comment: @JoséPereda I tried using WSL and I was getting an strange error when Clang tried to do compiling, something about "unexpected ")"" and I couldn't figure out how to solve and its cause.

So, I decided to use VM. In a Discord Java help server, I figured out that the problem was VM's RAM. I put 3.5 GB to it and in Java arguments for GraalVM, 2G for Mxm and Msm. It almost worked, but the terminal pop out at a point. Compiling a simple Hello World (without maven) in GraalVM took 3 minutes and a half.